# SQL Server aggregate function query error

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

My query

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, COUNT(*) AS totalRun 
FROM history 
ORDER BY starttime DESC`
```

Estimated outcome is all the data from 1 row in the history table with the latest `starttime` and a field`totalrun` with the total amount of records, but... I get the following error.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'history.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
example of the result:
[image: expected result]
These are all the fields of the row with the latest starttime in the history table with the extra COUNT field 'totalRun'

Comment: You forgot `group by` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregates can only be expressed in two cases.

1. Where you have a `GROUP BY` statement
2. Where you use the `OVER` clause

The following will give you the most recent start time and the number of rows in your source table that share that start time...

```
SELECT
  starttime,
  COUNT(*)  AS row_count
FROM
  history
GROUP BY
  starttime
ORDER BY
  starttime DESC
```

In this structure the *only* fields you can select are the ones in the `GROUP BY` statement *(and you can have several)*, or aggregates *(such as `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc).

If, however, you want the `COUNT(*)` to be done over the whole table, and not just the rows grouped together, you can use the `OVER` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS row_count
FROM
  history
ORDER BY
  starttime DESC
```

Because this doesn't use a `GROUP BY`, you can then also select `*` rather than just teh fields you are grouping by.

If you need something different, please could you include some example data and the results you would desire?

Comment: +1... Subquery `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history)` can also be used, but `OVER(PARTITION BY 1)` is faster and better option

Comment: The result would be the same as this query:
MySQL
`SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM history ORDER BY starttime LIMIT 0,1`

i just don't know how to do it in mssql

Comment: @GertKommer - MySQL allows you to include aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` statement, and to include fields that have not been grouped by.  This is fairly unusual, however, and MySQL documentation even states that the behaviour is arbitrary in many cases.  In MSSQL the required syntax is much more explicit, does not give arbitrary behaviour, and is actually more inline with other SQL dialects.  The use of the `OVER` clause seems to match your description.

Comment: Not sure that SQL Server allows `partition by 1`. An empty `over()` clause is more usual at least.

Comment: Now in a position to test this and yes it does allow it. It moans about `ORDER BY 1` which is why I thought it might not work.

Answer (score 3):

You either aggregate or group by a column. You have columns that are neither

```
SELECT TOP 1
   starttime, COUNT(*) AS totalRun
FROM history
GROUP BY starttime, foo
ORDER BY starttime DESC;
```

If you need a column `foo`, then add it as follows

```
SELECT TOP 1
   starttime, foo, COUNT(*) AS totalRun
FROM history
GROUP BY starttime, foo
ORDER BY starttime DESC, foo;
```

Comment: Op describes `and a field totalrun with the total amount of records`.  My understanding is that the OP wants `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)`?

Comment: @Dems: could be that simple. Good point. Make that your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I could not unerstand the requirement properly. Why you are using top 1 with count(*) 
and without the group by clause.

If you want the result TotalRuns earned on last date then you can use this query

```
SELECT TOP 1  starttime, COUNT(1) AS totalRun 
            FROM history Group by starttime ORDER BY starttime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the requirement:

Estimated outcome is all the data from 1 row in the history table with the latest starttime and a fieldtotalrun with the total amount of records,

select top 1 *
from 
(Select *
from history 
where starttime= (select max(starttime) from history) )i
full outer join
(select count(1) count , max(starttime) sttime as fieldtotalrun
from history ) j on i.starttime=j.sttime